# Cropping vertical countours in OpenCV, getting bounding box borders instead of area

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to extract columns of a table in an image using `opencv`. I have managed to successfully identify the vertical regions of interest as shown in the image below:

[image]

My problem is when I am trying to extract and save those regions of interest I am getting a 6 vertical lines of the border of the bounding rectangle as opposed to the region in between them.

This is the code I am using to achieve this:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('x.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,50))
vertical_mask = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=1)
 
cnts = cv2.findContours(vertical_mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12), -1)

idx = 0
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

    idx+=1
    new_img=image[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite(str(idx) + '.png', new_img)

cv2.imshow("im.png",image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Any ideas as to how I can solve this problem?
Edit: This [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArFPd.png) is is the image of the right most border, as you can see there is some text

Comment: Get the X coordinates of the vertical lines from Hough line transform and compute the crop regions from that.

Comment: I've tried the Hough line transform, however I'm not able to produce the correct region of interest as I have done above.

Answer (score 0):

The bounding boxes you are drawing are from each line, not from the columns. What you should do is take the two points from some line, take the other two points from the line next to it, and using this 4 points you have defined the rectangle which is your column.

All this, of course assuming they are sorted from left to right, by coordinates. But opencv doesn't guarantee us they are sorted that way.
So sort them first, and then draw rectangles over consecutive two lines